# Unwanted image resizing

Tags: jquery, css

I need to display thumbnails `30x30px + border + padding`

```css
.wihi3030 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

a.image30 img {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<a class="image30" href="#"><img class="wihi3030" src="#" alt="" /></a>
```

it works OK:

[correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC6hb.jpg)

30px + border + padding = 38px.

Yesterday I downloaded and installed a lightbox called Venobox -

For some reason the same image when I open it in a lightbox, reduces to `22x22px`
Together with border and padding it has size `30x30px`

[incorrect reduced size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF333.jpg)

How can I prevent resizing of the image?
I want them to stay `30x30px + border + padding` and not `30px` together with border and padding.

I have checked CSS files but can not understand what cause image resizing.

Comment: maybe add min-width:30px and min-height:30px to .wihi3030

Comment: They're probably using `box-sizing: border-box;` where the padding and border are included as part of the width and height declarations. With `box-sizing: border-box;` if you tell an element to be `300px` wide, it will be `300px` with or without padding and/or borders.

Comment: Go read up on the basic workings of the CSS Box Model, and then meet the `box-sizing` property. Btw., what sense does it even make to open a 30*30px image in a lightbox, only to see it there in the exact same size …?

Comment: You should be able to right click and inspect the element and check the computed CSS values. It should show you the CSS it applies to the elements, like `box-sizing`, etc.. Then compare it to the CSS generated in the working example and see what's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VenoBox uses [**`box-sizing: border-box;`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

> The width and height properties include the content, the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode. Note that padding and border will be inside of the box e.g.  .box {width: 350px; border: 10px solid black;} leads to a box rendered in the browser of width: 350px. The content box can't be negative and is floored to 0, making it impossible to use border-box to make the element disappear.
>
> Here the dimension is calculated as, *width = border + padding + width of the content, and height = border + padding + height of the content.*

Below are the CSS selectors that VenoBox uses to set `box-sizing`. Set it's value to `content-box` to prevent width and height from including padding and borders.

Include this set of selectors after the original selectors to override the original values.

```
.vbox-overlay *,
.vbox-overlay *:before,
.vbox-overlay *:after {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp can help to you.

If container has border-box property it makes that problem.

E.